# How can i retreive data from Web Server to my Intranet SP site

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-services, managed-metadata, sql-server, external-content-type

Would you please let us know the steps to connect a external Web Service that has specific attribute (GetAttributeProductsByID , GetAttributeProductsByName ... etc ) with an Intranet Sharepoint site

How can i retreive data from Web Server to my Intranet SP site:

1- I need to add the SP admin user to the Web Server SQL database as owner ?
   If yes, i give the user (Read, Wirte or Read/Write)

2- I need to configure the External database in SP designer 2010 or i retreive data by using the .net coding ?

Regards,
Hassib

Answer (score 2):

Hassib,

If you are using WCF Web Service to bring SQL Server data to your SharePoint environment, you can have a look at [How to: Create an External Content Type Based on a Web Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee556431.aspx)

You don't need to add SharePoint Admin account to SQL Server in this case, because database connection will be made by Web Service and Web Service account will be used for authentication... And you will need to use .NET for connecting database and writing functions...

However, if you are just looking for direct connection to database and do not need Web Service layer, then you will select SQL Server for External Content Type, here is a nice post:
[SharePoint 2010 using BCS with SQL Server database](http://blog.arjanfraaij.com/2011/07/sharepoint-2010-using-bcs-with-sql.html)
[Setting up External Content Type for SQL Server database using SQL Server authentication](http://wyldesharepoint.blogspot.com/2010/06/setting-up-external-content-type-for.html)

You can use SQL Server Authentication as well or provide a secure store ID which uses a pre-defined user to connect to your database in External Content Type [not necessary to be SharePoint Admin account]

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your quick reply and after my research about the Data Service that we need to use it ... it's the SOAP Service Connection:

Can you give me more blog link about this section since i am not able to display the Data retreived from the Web Service as HTML code ... i insert the SOAP data connection in the new page zone and its looks very bad !! the data cannot display as HTML code:

Please see below code as example:

```
ddw1:product_id 
4

ddw1:name Micro AB 50N Anti-Block Additive 

ddw1:image NoImage.png 

ddw1:description <p>Anti-blocking additive with 50% natural pure silica used with LLDPE carrier</p> 

ddw1:specifications  "Note that i removed all < to be able to show the display of the code that was retreived"

 ul> li>Reduce polymers' inter-surface cohesion from occurring, br> /li> li>Increase br> /li>  li>consumers can easily open bags  br> /li> li>Ensure good transparency &amp; minimal effect on the coefficient of friction br> /li> /ul> p style="margin-bottom: 0in;"> strong>Color /strong> strong> br> /strong>Natural /p> <p style="margin-bottom: 0in;"> strong>Ingredients /strong> strong> br> /strong>Active: 50% very pure Natural Silica. Inert with other additives<br> Carrier: LLDPE  br>  br>  /p>  strong>Dosage /strong> strong> br>  /strong>0 application&nbsp; br>
```

Please help us, to know how can display the below code as normal Html display ??
Regards,

Comment: Is this a new question? It is hard to tell what you're asking here. Also, I attempted to format your post a little bit using the format code button. Please edit your question / answer again.